# Grails Running App errors since added Databaseconnection

Tags: grails, jdbc

Hello Dear Programmers,

I'm learning to work with Groovy / Grails with the eBook "Grails - A Quick Start Guide" and now im working there with an example project called TekDays. Every step for this project is documented and well described but i cant find an fault i made.. 
I'm using the Grovvy / Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) as IDE.

- Grails Version: 2.2.4
- Groovy/Grails Tool Suite Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE

Everything worked fine but since I added the database connection to my MySQL database I'm getting this error:

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2014-01-07 10:29:32,352 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR    context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':  Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager':   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties':  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector':  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
->> 1429 | createConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1371 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
->>   59 | findClass in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    424 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    357 | loadClass in     ''
|   1420 | createConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1371 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

This is the `DataSource.groovy` file where i added the database connection like it's done in the eBook:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "admin"
    password = "root"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/:tekdays"
        }
    }
    test {
         dataSource {
             dbCreate = "update"
             url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
         }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`BuildConfig.groovy` :

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5  or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable  ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation,  not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

       // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

If more information is needed, I will add it as fast as i can.

Thank you very much for every helpful answer or comment!

Comment: What's `BuildConfig.groovy` look like?

Comment: added BuildConfig.groovy :)

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting `// runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lukas, you need to add the jdbc-driver in you /lib-folder and add the correct dependency in your BuldConfig.groovy, for example:

```
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
```

Of course depending on the version that you're using.

Back in the day I also did this example and I know that they mention this.

Give it a go!

Comment: Uncommenting runtime in dependencies and changing to my version was the solution. Thank you very much! I wont stop till TekDays is finished ;D

Comment: Don't give up! It's a great example that will teach you a wide variety of things that can be done with Grails!

Comment: Don't add anything in the lib folder - the BuildConfig.groovy dependency you showed is the correct solution.