# Connect MySQL in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I just now trying connect MySQL data base in Grails.
This is my old data base configuration:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
               // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've coppied in DataSource.groovy example from a docs, I know, what in my case, something of it may be wrong:

```
    dataSource {
 pooled = true
 jmxExport = true
 url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/:my_database"
 driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
 username = "sa"
 password = ""
}
hibernate {
 cache.use_second_level_cache = true
 cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
 cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
 singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
 flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
 development {
     dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
         url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/:my_database"
     }
 }
 test {
     dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/:my_database"
     }
 }
 production {
     dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/:my_database"
         properties {
            // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
            jmxEnabled = true
            initialSize = 5
            maxActive = 50
            minIdle = 5
            maxIdle = 25
            maxWait = 10000
            maxAge = 10 * 60000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
            validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout = 3
            validationInterval = 15000
            testOnBorrow = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            testOnReturn = false
            jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
            defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Also, I've downloaded an archive with such content: docs folder, src folder, my-sql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar. I've moved this jar-file in lib folder of my project.
These errors I get when my project run:

```
2015-04-21 15:33:19,986 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Comment: make sure mysql listen `localhost:3306`, try `telnet localhost 3306` to test it, for example

Comment: also I suggest with basic configuration, w/o `properties` section. and only after you'll get it working, only then use custom options, if you really need it

Comment: am not sure about this but do you really need to manually download the mysql connector. On my project I a only seeing `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24' `dependency on build config ( I did not setup my project myself.)

Comment: @Igor Artamonov, localhost wasn't started. It has been fixed. Also I add 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24' dependency. And dbCreate-value has been changed to create. Now I get such error:
Message: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'my_database'. How it may be if username-value is not empty string? PS. Also I've set up an empty password.

Comment: @pragmus please provide your edited datasource.

Comment: @Ramsharan, provided!

Comment: Else one error is: Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Comment: Are you using ':' infront of database name? You are using ' :my_database'

Comment: @Ramsharan, first time I don't use ':', but then I've done it relying on this source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968506/grails-running-app-errors-since-added-databaseconnection

Comment: May be I need to update my jdk.Source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968506/grails-running-app-errors-since-added-databaseconnection

Comment: I have never use ':'.

Comment: @Ramsharan, database must be created automatically from grails request,does not it?

Comment: No database is not created by grails. You have to create database and tables are created.

Comment: It means you have not created database yet.